# Error during installation of PyPi "sshtunnel" package on fedora

Tags: linux, pip, python-3.7, fedora, ssh-tunnel

When I do "pip3 install sshtunnel" on my Fedora31 I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cf_emmbs/sshtunnel/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cf_emmbs/sshtunnel/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-98qrjgt1
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cf_emmbs/sshtunnel/
Complete output (23 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-cf_emmbs/sshtunnel/setup.py", line 14, in 
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 18, in 
from .build_py import _unique_everseen
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 16, in 
from setuptools.lib2to3_ex import Mixin2to3
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/lib2to3_ex.py", line 12, in 
from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool, get_fixers_from_package
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/refactor.py", line 26, in 
from .fixer_util import find_root
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/fixer_util.py", line 7, in 
from .pygram import python_symbols as syms
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/pygram.py", line 32, in 
python_grammar = driver.load_packaged_grammar("lib2to3", _GRAMMAR_FILE)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/pgen2/driver.py", line 156, in load_packaged_grammar
return load_grammar(grammar_source)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/pgen2/driver.py", line 131, in load_grammar
g.load(gp)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib2to3/pgen2/grammar.py", line 108, in load
d = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have pip3 and setuptools updated at the last version.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you try the same install in a virtual environment, does it work?  I.e., `mkdir playdir;cd playdir;python3 -m venv myvenv;source myvenv/bin/activate;pip3 install -UI pip setuptools;pip3 install sshtunnel`

Comment: @rickhg12hs still not working. i had to install a virtual box with ubuntu in order to make it work.
It seems to be a problem of  `d = pickle.load(f)`

Comment: That's disappointing. I successfully installed `sshtunnel` on an older Fedora. The errors were the same in the virtual environment?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes